Rabbitmq starts on boot after few mins it exited
rabbitmq server starts on boot but after 1 min it gets stopped due to below error. I am using rabbitmq-server (3.12.12). if again i restart the rabbitmq service is working here
2024-07-23 20:06:09.242881-07:00 [info] <0.1459.0> stopped TCP listener on [::]:5672
2024-07-23 20:06:09.243663-07:00 [error] <0.1463.0> Error on AMQP connection <0.1463.0> (127.0.0.1:49298 -> 127.0.0.1:5672, vhost: '/', user: 'guest', state: running), channel 0:
2024-07-23 20:06:09.243663-07:00 [error] <0.1463.0>  operation none caused a connection exception connection_forced: "broker forced connection closure with reason 'shutdown'"
2024-07-23 20:06:09.245219-07:00 [info] <0.1502.0> Closing all connections in vhost '/' on node 'rabbit@node-009701000078-internal' because the vhost is stopping

i have increased delay after rabbitmq-server  starts but it not helps and enable amqp plugins and reenable rabbitmq-management plugin .
